# Oracle AQ call back with Reactive Extension and transaction ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions, queue, system.reactive

I have implemented dequeuing of messages from Oracle AQ and exposing it to the system as IObservable. The workflow is as follows:-

1. Application receives a call back event from Oracle about a new message.
2. Application de-queues the message and add it to IObservable (Message is dequeued as part of a transaction which is committed as soon as the message is dequeued).

I realized a potential issue and that is when the message is dequeued, the transaction is committed straight away rather than waiting for it to be consumed successfully by the application. Below is the code which I am using but need a suggestion where/how to commit the transaction after it has been consumed successfully by the application. Currently it starts and commits/rollbacks the transaction in the private Dequeue method.

```
public sealed class Queue<T> : IQueue<T> where T : IQueueDataType
{
    private readonly OracleConnection _connection;

    private readonly string _consumerName;

    private readonly IQueueSetting _queueSetting;

    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _dbConnectionFactory;

    private OracleAQQueue _queue;

    private IObservable<T> _messages;

    private bool _isDisposed;

    public Queue(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory, IDalSettings dalSettings, IQueueSetting queueSetting)
    {
        _dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
        _connection = dbConnectionFactory.Create() as OracleConnection;
        _consumerName = dalSettings.Consumer;
        _queueSetting = queueSetting;

    }

    public void Connect()
    {            
        _connection.Open();
        _queue = new OracleAQQueue(_queueSetting.QueueName, _connection)
        {
            DequeueOptions = { Wait = 10, Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.Immediate , ConsumerName = _consumerName, NavigationMode = OracleAQNavigationMode.FirstMessage, DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Remove},
            UdtTypeName = _queueSetting.QueueDataTypeName,
            MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt
        };

        _queue.NotificationConsumers = new[] { _consumerName };

        _messages = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<OracleAQMessageAvailableEventHandler, OracleAQMessageAvailableEventArgs>(
                h => _queue.MessageAvailable += h, h => _queue.MessageAvailable -= h)
            .Where(x => x.EventArgs.AvailableMessages > 0)
            .Select(x =>
            {
                try
                {
                Log.Info("Msg received", "Queue", _queueSetting.QueueName);

                    OracleAQMessage msg = Dequeue();

                    Log.Info("Msg received id " + msg.MessageId, "Queue", _queueSetting.QueueName);
                    return (T)msg.Payload;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }).Publish().RefCount();

    }

    private OracleAQMessage Dequeue()
    {
        using (var connection = _dbConnectionFactory.Create() as OracleConnection)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        OracleAQMessage msg = _queue.Dequeue();
                        **transaction.Commit();**
                        return msg;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {                           
                        **transaction.Rollback();**
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(string.Format("Error occurred while connecting to database to dequeue new message. Error : {0}", e),
                    "Dequeue", GetType().FullName);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public IObservable<T> GetMessages()
    {
        return _messages;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {           
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (_queue != null)
            {
                _queue.Dispose();    
            }

            _connection.Dispose();
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If rather than using `IObservable`, I just expose an event committing and rolling back transaction would be very easy but I like what I can do with `IObservable` i.e I can run a `Linq` but don't know how to commit the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy fix here. If I understand this correctly:

1. An event is pushed from Oracle,
2. You want to expose the event via an `IObservable` stream,
3. The application 'handles' it,
4. You want to commit if handled successfully, roll-back if not.

The problem is that `IObservable` is a one-way mechanism. Once you publish a message (in our case that you got something from this Oracle queue), the intention isn't to track it, and decide later whether to commit/rollback. So your options are pretty much to stuff your app-logic into a handler of some form:

```
Func<OracleMessage, bool> isMessageCommitable; //...application handling logic here

var appHandledMessages = oracleSourceMessages
    .Select(m => Tuple.Create(m, isMessageCommitable(m)))
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();

appHandledMessages
    .Where(t => t.Item2)
    .Subscribe(t => Commit(t.Item1));

appHandledMessages
    .Where(t => !t.Item2)
    .Subscribe(t => Rollback(t.Item1));
```

...or to set up `IObservable`s pointing the other way which would push from the application back to the queue which messages should be committed/rolled back. You would probably want two, one for committing, one for rolling back, and those should probably be passed into the constructor of `Queue<T>`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide an example of the second case "IObservables pointing the other way ..........."